# Is there is a right way to use scripts to disable Passthrough mode in my app which is developed with MRTK and Quest 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, mrtk

Unity 2020.3.22f1
MRTK 2.8
Oculus XR Plugins 1.10.0
I used MRTK and deploy to Quest2. In my unity scene,MixedRealityToolkit—>Input—>Input Data Provider—>XR SDK Oculus Devices Manager—>Prefab reference—>Ovr Camera Rig Prefab, i filled it with OVRCameraRig prefab in Assets\Oculus\VR\Prefabs. The prafab has a componment OVR Manager which has a property "Enable Passthrough" checkbox.I controled the checkbox by code like this:

```
public GameObject MRTK_Quest_OVRCameraRig;
public void EnableInsightPassthrough(bool pass) 
{ 
  MRTK_Quest_OVRCameraRig.GetComponent<OVRManager>().isInsightPassthroughEnabled = pass; 
}
```

in unity scene,i drag the prefab to fill "public GameObject MRTK_Quest_OVRCameraRig",i used a button to call this function.When played in editor, i can see the checkbox is switching by checking and unchecking,but in Quest 2, it the passthrough mode was not switching.If enable passthrough at the beginning, it always passthrough mode no matter how I click the button in Quest 2,if disable passthrough at the beginning, it always non-passthrough mode. I doubt that MRTK donest receive the change of state, like data refresh.
so ,what is the right way to switch passthrough mode by code?Please forgive me for develiping in corporate Intranet, i cant upload image.

I had try another way to access the Ovr Camera Rig,like that:
`CoreServices.InputSystem.InputSystemProfile.DataProviderConfigurations......`
but cant access the Enable Passthrough property.